# Syncing specific local and remote folders on Google Drive (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, google-drive

I need to sync a **specific local folder** (and subfolders) on an Ubuntu machine with a **specific remote folder** on Google Drive.  I've found a few programs that let me select a specific local folder but all of the programs I've tried so far don't let me specify a remote folder (they always sync with the root folder).

I'd like something that will monitor both local and remote files and respond to changes by syncing automatically.

Can anyone suggest a program?

Comment: I haven't used it but [rclone](https://rclone.org/docs/) says you can do things like `rclone sync /local/path remote:path`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I tried it.  But I'm looking for something that will run in the background and sync changes as they happen.  Yes; I know that I could make a cronjob - and I'll do that if I can't find another solution - but I'd like something that's as responsive as possible without having to make a very frequent job.